# php docker permission error, how could i solve it?

Tags: php, docker, permissions, laravel-8

I tried to run my php app in docker
and got this permission error:
[image]

nginx conf file

```
# /nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen 9001 default_server;
    server_name notification-app;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass   notification-app:9000;
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
}
```

this is my dockerfile i add `chmod 777` and try with 775 it did not work
also with

```
--chown=www-data:www-data m
```

using the following docker file to build and run php laravel app

```
# /php/Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2-fpm



#Install dependencies
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get upgrade -y; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
            curl \
            libmemcached-dev \
            libz-dev \
            libpq-dev \
            libjpeg-dev \
            libpng-dev \
            libfreetype6-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            libwebp-dev \
            libxpm-dev \
            libmcrypt-dev \
            libonig-dev; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN set -eux; \
    # Install the PHP pdo_mysql extention
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql; \
    # Install the PHP pdo_pgsql extention
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql; \
    # Install the PHP gd library
    docker-php-ext-configure gd \
            --prefix=/usr \
            --with-jpeg \
            --with-webp \
            --with-xpm \
            --with-freetype; \
    docker-php-ext-install gd; \
    php -r 'var_dump(gd_info());'
# ARG UID
# ARG GID



WORKDIR /var/www/html
# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
COPY .. /var/www/html
# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www .. /var/www/html

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1


COPY --from=composer:2.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

COPY ./composer.* ./


RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN php artisan horizon:install
# run composer dump-autoload --optimize
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

in addition i've create this docker compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  #nginx
  web-nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - notification-app
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - laravel
  notification-app:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./php-docker/dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=${UID:-1000}
        - GID=${GID:-1000}
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - laravel
  postgres-db:
    image: postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./db/storage/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/conf.d/:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
      - ./db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
      - ./db/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
      - ./db/sql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: notification
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123123
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust" 
    ports:
      - 5323:5432
    networks:
      - laravel

volumes:
  postgres-db:
  postgresql.conf:
  schema.sql:
  init.sql:
  create_tables.sh:

networks:
  laravel:
```

Now I use

docker-compose build

which created image successfully, and now I want to run the image with docker-compose up

And I got the permission error